# Solving differential equations in realtime in a webapp

Tags: python, web-applications, ode

Is this undoable?  Say I have a complex system of differential equations that I want to have a live user-based input to them and then I want to plot the results in real time.  It doesn't seem like javascript has the precision or mathematical dexterity.  My initial thought was to use python with scipy for ode solving + django for user interaction and displaying, but I assume that the cross-talk between server and client would take way too long.

Comment: You want to numerically solve the ODE? I see no reason why javascript would not be able to do this, although you might have to do all the legwork yourself. You could use scipy and django. But one problem I see there is that it'll take a while (and a number of steps) to solve the ODEs. You plan to do multiple requests? If so, how do you maintain state?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.numericjs.com/ they have an ODE solver example, you can see it in action here: http://www.numericjs.com/workshop.php?link=fdd38094da018f6071cb2d51d47c7fb3de869cb5dd0b4f3b677b480ce7ffbd31.

Comment: A long time ago, when I first had a go at this problem, I had read that javascript didn't have the precision for scientific computing.  Maybe it's changed or that one source was wrong or I just misread it.  As for maintaining state, that's the problem.  Let's say, for instance, that mouse position represents some generic input to the ode.  Ideally, I'd want every time step to factor in the user's mouse position, but that's probably unrealistic if I want to maintain realtime results.  The systems I'm imagining are likely to have about 60-80 differential equations in them.

Comment: @blubber, I saw numeric javascript when I was looking around.  Would the user have to have the package themselves to be able to use the web app?  I have very little experience with javascript

Comment: You download that numeric js source (probably a couple files) and put it on your server. Then use <script> tags in your HTML to link to it. User doesn't need to install anything, just visit your webpage. You can even use that offline if you want. No need to install anything, or write a webapp. And look at that beautiful Lorentz attractor :].

Comment: One a sidenote, you are completely dependent on the user's machine and javascript implementation. Unlike software like Octave or R, the javascript implementation in your browser is not optimized for this kind of task. So the performance will be orders of magnitude slower then when one would use specialized software. It depends on your specific circumstances whether that is acceptable to you or not.

Comment: I see.  This may be a problem.  I won't know until implementation.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: Absolutely no problem at all and good luck to you :). You can always fiddle with the parameters of whatever solver they use, maybe you can tune it's precision down for slow computers.

Comment: You could also try https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki in combination with odeint.com . It is a real C++ to js Compiler and it can optimize the js code. odeint is a very modern and high performant ODE solver for C++. I would really like to see the result of this approach.

Comment: hrm, there's an odeint module in python,  I wonder if its the same.  I have no experience with c++.